# Copy and paste a DXF Polygon from Deed Plotter to a Shapefile in ArcViewer troubles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, editing

I am creating an easement layer in ArcViewer by using Deed Plotter to create the shape of the easement and then adding the dxf file as a layer in ArcViewer.  Then I start an edit session, editing the Easement.shp layer so that I can select the dxf layer, copy, and paste it into the Easement.shp.  However, recently I started to get the error: "The features could not be copied because the target layer is the wrong geometry type.  Item not found in this collection."  The Easement.shp is a polygon layer and the dxf is a polygon.  Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You're certain they're polygons and not just closed polylines? Obviously if you've added it as a layer to Arc, it will tell you it's either a polyline layer or a polygon layer and the default symbology should be a dead giveaway, but this isn't entirely clear in your question. Beyond that cndnflyr's answer would be the next thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Attribute Table of the DXF - Polygon layer.  It is sometimes a PolygonZ Shape or something like that.

If this is the case use the Feature Class to Feature Class Tool to copy it to a SHP file.  You'll need to set the 'Output has Z Values' Environment Variable when you run the tool:

[image]